# How can I display the anchorpoint for a CCNode in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, anchor

Is there a way to display a CCNode's anchor point?  This would be very useful for debugging.

Comment: [name of node].anchorPoint.x and y. you can log this into the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not built-in, but you could [draw a point or circle](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest_2.x/cocos2d-iphone/html/_c_c_drawing_primitives_8h.html#a34d0ad7b8f0d0dbd5fb874d607d69f1d) at the anchor point location using the anchorPointInPoints property.

```
-(void) draw
{
    [super draw];
    ccDrawCircle(self.anchorPointInPoints, 20, 0, 8, YES);
}
```

Of course, I always recommend **not** to change the anchorPoint in the first place. The alternative is to add the node to a parent node, offset it from the parent, and then the parent's position acts like the anchorpoint for the child node. The advantage is that methods like boundingBox aren't offset from the node's position (can be an issue for hit detection), and you can rotate the child node around its center point and around its parent.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked, just adding in a call to the superclass:  `-(void) draw
{
    [super draw];
    ccDrawCircle(self.anchorPointInPoints, 20, 0, 8, YES);
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the anchor point of a CCNode with

```
- (CGPoint) anchorPointInPixels
```

which is a readonly method. Afterwards, you have several ways of actually marking the spot. You could use

```
- ccDrawCircle()
```

while overriding the draw method or alternatively put up a texture on that point, if you want something fancier.